# NumPy: Calculate mean of certain elements in array

Tags: python, numpy, mean

Assuming an (1-d) array, is it possible to calculate the average on given groups of diifferent size without looping? Instead of

```
avgs = [One_d_array[groups[i]].mean() for i in range(len(groups))]
```

Something like

```
avgs = np.mean(One_d_array, groups)
```

Basically I want to do this:

```
M = np.arange(10000)
np.random.shuffle(M)
M.resize(100,100)
groups = np.random.randint(1, 10, 100)

def means(M, groups):
    means = []
    for i, label in enumerate(groups):
        means.extend([M[i][groups == j].mean() for j in set(p).difference([label])])
    return means
```

This runs at

```
%timeit means(M, groups)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop
```

Speed up of 10 times or so would be already great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you see a loop or not, there is a loop.
Here's one way, but the loop is simply hidden in the call to [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: groups = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]

In [12]: map(np.mean, groups)
Out[12]: [1.5, 4.0]
```

Comment: I guess your're right. However, is there any way to make calculation of mean faster? It's a bottleneck in several functions I'm dealing with..

Comment: A NumPy array can be fast when you apply NumPy functions such a `np.mean` to a single large array. NumPy may not be very fast if you have to call `np.mean` on lots of small arrays. If you can't arrange your data into a single large array (maybe because the rows have different lengths) then you may be better off using plain Python lists than lots of small NumPy arrays. (It's hard to tell -- you have to benchmark with `timeit`.)

Comment: If you are computing the mean of `groups` over and over again (with small changes to `groups` in between iterations) then it would be smart to keep running totals of the sum of each item in `groups`. That way you can update the totals as `groups` changes, and it is easy and quick to compute the new means.

Answer (score 0):

Another hidden loop is the use of [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> groups = [[0,1,2], [3,4]]
>>> np.vectorize(lambda group: np.mean(x[group]), otypes=[float])(groups)
array([ 2. , 4.5])
```